# In proof of the surjectivity of $\operatorname{Div}(X) \to \operatorname{Pic}(X)$, $D \mapsto \mathcal{O}_X(D)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm reading the Gortz's Algebraic Geometry, Proposition 11.27 and stuck at understanding some statement :

[image]
[image]

Why the underlined statement true? There $\mathcal{K}_X$ is the sheaf of total fractions of $\mathcal{O}_X$. We can identify $\mathcal{O}_X$ with a subsheaf of rings of $\mathcal{K}_X$ (c.f. Gortz's book, p.300).

By "s can be considered as a section $ t \in \Gamma(U, \mathcal{K}_X)$", I understood as next isomorphism ( Gortz's book , p. 175 ; substitute $U$ to $X$ and $\mathcal{K}_X|_U$ to $\mathcal{F}$) :

[image]

Now, for simplicity, let $U=X$. Then we have an isomorphism of $\Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$-modules :

$$ \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\mathcal{O}_X, \mathcal{K}_X) \to \Gamma(X, \mathcal{K}_X)$$

$$\omega \mapsto \omega_X(1) $$

So, my question is, for $\omega : \mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{K}_X $ , $\omega$ is injective if and only if $\omega_X(1) \in \Gamma(X, \mathcal{K}_X)^{\times}$ ?

1. 'Only if' direction : since $\omega$ is injection, $\omega_X : \Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_X) \to \Gamma(X, \mathcal{K}_X)$ is also injection of $\Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$-module. Note that $\omega_X(1)$ may not be $1_{\mathcal{K}_X(X)}$ since $\omega_X$ may not be a ring homomorphism. (Am I following well?). Since we can identify $\mathcal{O}_X$ with a subsheaf of $\mathcal{K}_X$, we can view $\Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ as a subring of $\Gamma(X, \mathcal{K}_X)$. So we are done if next statement-which I formulated in my own-is true :

> Let $A$, $B$ be commutative rings with unity. $B$ is a $A$-module and contains $A$ as a subring. Let $f : A \to B$ be a injective $A$-module homomorphism. Then $f(1_A) \in B^{\times}$?

And is this statement true?

2. And how about "If" direction?  $\omega_X(1) \in \Gamma(X, \mathcal{K}_X)^{\times}$ implies the injectivity of $\omega$ ?

Or is there any other way to show the above underlined statement?

Can anyone help?

Comment: Your statement is not true: for example, take $A=\mathbb Z, B=\mathbb Z[x]$ and $f(1_A)=x$. Intuitively, I think that a global section of $\mathcal K_X$ is invertible iff it does not vanish identically on some non-empty open subset, and it is equivalent to injectivity of $\omega$.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for the late comment. I have been on a trip :) Perhaps, can you explain your intuition more friendly and formally?

Comment: I meant the following: a global section of $\mathcal K_X$ is locally a fraction $f/g$ with regular $f$ and $g$. It is invertible iff $f$ is invertible as a section of this sheaf, iff $f$ is not locally a zero divisor, iff $f$ does not vanish on any nonempty open subset. This is only an intuition, not a formal argument.

Comment: @danneks : Yes I will try it first, and ask again. Thank you.